# How to disable storing of claims principal records in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Azure B2C stores information about every claims principal logged in.
We do not need this information. 
Users should be just passed through B2C from IdPs to service provider.
How to disable storing users information in B2C?

Comment: It's not possible. You need at least the Username/email, phone (for MFA) and password.

Comment: Why is it not possible? Users are authenticated outside. Why do B2C needs to store anything about users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found.
The base policy in SignIn userjourney

```
<UserJourney Id="SignIn">
```

contains an orchestration step that calls a technical profile **AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId**

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

This step creates user registrations in Azure B2C.

If this user journey is overloaded in an extension policy and this step skipped there then users will not be created.

Another step that checks users registration with id **AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError**

```
TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError"
```

can also be skipped.

The authentication process with an external identity providers goes on flawlessly without these steps.

Comment: If you don't create the user object and you are using refresh tokens, can you exchange it for another ID or access token?

Comment: I don't know. This question should be answered by Azure B2C team.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C does not store anything if you are using an external identity provider.  But if you are using Azure AD B2C's idedntity provider, It will store the claims within it.

Hope the information helps.

Comment: Yes it stores by default. B2C generates users like cpim_{guid}@{idp_domain}

Comment: Sorry for the last misinformed comment, Just read that it stores the following info:
The default scopes used for our supported set of social identity providers are:

Facebook: email
Google+: email
Microsoft account: openid email profile
Amazon: profile
LinkedIn: r_emailaddress, r_basicprofile

You can take it as, Azure AD B2C keeps it as a primary key in any DB and uses it while calling its Graph API for that Primary key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs

You can refer the info here as well